# Cocos2d: Get current position of scene in CCActionEase

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, uikit, position, layer, scene

I need to sync the position of a UIKit layer with a Cocos2D scene layer what a transition occurs which shifts the current scene off the screen with a new one.   I have edited CCActionEase to make my own update method which could presumably call a method in my delegate to send the current position of my Cocos2D scene layer.  All I need is a way to somehow get the current position of the scene in CCActionEase.  It needs to be here, because CCActionEase calls update over and over, and while it is, the scene's position is changing.

Here is a run down of my code in order things are called.

In my scenes current layer my transition's method is called:

`[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene: [ExitUTransition transitionWithDuration:5.4 scene: [JoinedMapsScene scene]]];`

In that class my custom CCEaseInWithPercentMult's actionWithAction is called:

```
@implementation ExitUTransition

- (CCActionInterval*)easeActionWithAction:(CCActionInterval*)action {

    return [CCEaseInWithPercentMult actionWithAction:action rate:1.0f];

}

@end
```

In CCActionEase, the update method is called:

```
@implementation CCEaseInWithPercentMult
-(void) update: (ccTime) t
{

    [other update: powf(t,rate)];

    //here I could pass the scene layer position

    [(cocosTestsAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] adjustBGViewPosWithXOffset:scenePosX withYOffset:scenePosY];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not override the setPosition of the layer you are moving? I use this technique in an application of mine to move a UITextField with a layer and it works fine.

```
-(void)setPosition:(CCPoint)p
{
      [super setPosition:p];
      CGPoint uiKitPoint = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToUI:p];

      //Move the UIKit object wherever
}
```

Comment: That looks like a really cool method of moving a UIKit thing with a layer, but can I still use it in my case where I'm using a scene transition like CCActionEase?